# How to split a dataframe row into several rows if they're above a certain word count?

Tags: r, dataframe, kable, kableextra, freetext

I have a dataframe that is made up of two columns. One column has a numbered value, and the next column is free text. One entry has a prodigious number of words (2k +), and that is making it hard to create a table of that data frame in a .pdf file with the kable package. Is there anyway to split this row into two after a certain word or character limit is reached?

EDIT:

Basically make something that looks like this:

```
data.frame(first_column  = 14569,
                  second_column = "non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis"
          )
```

And turn that into a data frame that looks like this:

```
data.frame(first_column  = c("14569","14569","14569"),
                  second_column = c("non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam" , "id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis" , " aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis")
          )
```

Comment: Have you looked at `stringr::str_wrap` to insert newline characters? Or perhaps just truncating the offending cell? Difficult to know without a reproducible example.

Comment: Please share data with `dput` and what you have tried, alternatively, wait for a mind reader or an extraordinary hacker that can spy on your R session.

Answer (score 0):

May this help?

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(first_column  = 14569,
           second_column = "non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis"
)


df |> 
  mutate(second_column = paste(strwrap(second_column, width = 200), collapse = "\n")) |> 
  tidyr::separate_rows(2, sep = "\n") |> 
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE) |> 
  kable_styling(full_width = TRUE, latex_options = "scale_down")

# different option
df |> 
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE) |> 
  kable_styling(full_width = TRUE, latex_options = "scale_down")
```
````